# How to define Data Mapping in autosar arxml file

Tags: autosar

How I can define Data Mapping in the arxml file .

I want to define relation between system signal and datatypes.

I don't know what are the rules i need to follow while doing this?.Is there help available for this on internet.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the specification? Your question is very generic may have a higher chance to be answered if you quote specific parts of the specification and ask specific questions.

Comment: Could you please suggest me which specification i need to read?.I am very new to Autosar arxml still i try to make some changes in my question

Comment: The Data mapping itself and the signal-end is described in the TPS System template. The data-end is described in the TPS SoftwareComponentTemplate.